# Как сделать музыку или звук на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Как сделать музыку или звук на python?
И еще один вопрос, если вдруг можно написать то что будет весить меньше .mp3 или .py ?

Comment: Что подразумевается под словом «сделать»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй модули playsound, winsound, pyaudio.

Comment: Сяб, а насчет второго вопроса что думаете?

Comment: Просто я слышала, что одна буква весит 8 бит

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь, но количество букв не влияет на вес файла.

Comment: Вы это серьезно???  .mp3  -  это медиофайл, .py  -  скрипт на Python. Что с чем сравнивать вы собрались? Какие буквы по 8 бит? Какие буквы в медиафайлах?  В музыке или звуках?

Comment: Извините, не понял вопроса,

Comment: я думал вы про mp3

Comment: 1 латинский символ - 1 байт, 1 символ кириллицы - 2 байта

Comment: passant, я просто искала способ сделать игру как можно меньше, а то вдруг соберусь портировать на мобилки, а игра будет весить 100 мегабайт.
Но я видела видуо в интернете когда писали код, ну там ноты актавы смена инструментов и выключение этих самых нот, но это все очень геморно.

Comment: Если захочешь програму на мобилки делай через kivy